# How do you return only x number of records back

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an n API using Spring Boot to return the data back from my MySQL db.

I would like to send in a parameter (to keep it simple as part of the URI) to only return an x amount of records back.

My question is

1. Is it easier to just return all the records back in the Spring Boot app and then only loop through al the records and return the x amount of records back via an Arraylist or
2. Is there an actual method I can call with either JPA or the standard super class CRUD from Java to get the correct result?

Comment: Do you mean something like this [Pagination in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results#2-pageable)?

Comment: You can limit the results from the sql it self using a LIMIT clause if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use native query in your repository.
For example you have controller named fetch_data_controller and a repository name fetch_data_repository and a table name fetch_data_table from where you have to fetch only specific data.

In fetch_data_repository write the query as follows:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT col_1,col_2 FROM fetch_data_table WHERE validation = 1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Map<String,String>> fetch_data_func();
```

In fetch_data_controller write code as follows:

```
List<Map<String,String>> fetched_data = fetch_data_repository.fetch_data_func();
```